# How to stop calling next on infinite scroll when scroll goes on top?

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I'm using `infinite-scroll` on my project. The problem is that when I scroll to the top of the window, the `next` function will be called, and a request will be sent for fetching new data. It should be called `next` when I scroll to the bottom of the list.

Here's the use case of `InfiniteScroll`:

```
 <InfiniteScroll dataLength={notificationList.length} 
                 next={this.fetchMoreData} 
                 hasMore={this.state.hasMore} 
                 loader={ <div className={'text-center'}>{Utils.i18n('loadingList', true)}</div>}> {notificationList.length > 0 && notificationList.map((item, index) => { return ( <div key={item.id} name={"scroll-to-element-" + item.id} className={"notification-wrap"}>
     <div className={"row"}>
       <div className={"col-auto"}>
         <h4 className={"title"}> {item.title} </h4>
       </div>
       <div className={"col-auto mr-auto"}>
         <span className={"date"}> {item.createdAt} </span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div className={"description"}>
       <blockquote> {item.description} </blockquote>
     </div>
   </div> ); })} 
</InfiniteScroll> 
{notificationList.length === 0 && !notificationListLoading&& 
 <div className={"text-center my-4"}> {Utils.i18n('noData', true)} </div> }
```

And `fetchMoreData`:

```
  fetchMoreData = () => {
        if (this.props.notificationSettingReducer.notificationsList) {
            if (this.state.page < this.props.notificationSettingReducer.notificationsList.totalPages) {
                this.setState({
                    page: this.state.page + 1
                }, () => {
                    this.getNotification();
                });
            }
            if (this.state.page === this.props.notificationSettingReducer.notificationsList.totalPages) {
                this.setState({hasMore: false});
            }
        }
    };
```

It calls the `next` function on both the bottom and top. How can I stop `InfiniteScroll` from calling `next` and fetching new data when scrolling to the top or `window.scrollY == 0`?

Comment: remove down={(e)=> e.preventDefault()}

Comment: @RitikBanger it doesn't have any prop with mentioned signature.

Comment: Line No. 4 in the above code

Comment: @RitikBanger It doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**You can handle this using IntersectionObserver**
You can add div after list and add an observer on that div. once that div is visible you can call an API.

```js
const useIntersectionObserver = (ref, callback) => {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        callback();
      }
    });
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref && !ref.current) return;
    observer.observe(ref.current);
    return () => observer.unobserve(ref.current);
  }, [ref.current]);
};

const MainExample = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(Array(10).fill(0));
  useIntersectionObserver(ref, () => {
    console.log("Visible");
    setState((prev) => [...prev, ...Array(10).fill(0)]);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {state.map((_, index) => (<h1 key={index}>Hello {index + 1}</h1>))}
      <div ref={ref} />
    </div>
  );
};
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("mail"));
root.render(<MainExample />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mail"></div>
```

Comment: I don't like to change the package, but anyway thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollY==0`

for the top &
`ScrollY==document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight`

for the bottom

Comment: What can I do with this answer?!